# How to detect false data feed from Chainlink oracles

Tags: oracles, chainlink

I understand Chainlink uses explicit and implicit staking to enforce honest behavior. However, what is the mechanism used to catch the misbehavior of oracles (i.e., reporting wrong data)?

Answer (score 2):

Details of the process is outlined on page 88 of the [Chainlink 2.0 whitepaper](https://research.chain.link/whitepaper-v2.pdf). Essentially, nodes are also 'watchdogs' that can report bad data to the second-tier committee. The strong bribery resistance achieved by the CL staking mechanism relies fundamentally on slashed funds being awarded to these alerters/watchdogs. If you're asking on how this is actually done, then the details of the implementation of these concepts are not yet available, as Chainlink explicit staking isn't implemented yet

Comment: thanks for your answer; however, how it is detected currently on chainlink? I am aware of lack of stking and 2.0 whitepaper

Comment: Explicit staking isn't implemented yet. The 2.0 whitepaper outlines a roadmap that maps out the functionality and features CL will have over the coming months/years.

Chainlink in it's current form implements implicit staking,  details are in the whitepaper 2.0